# Printing array in batch file using variable index, having trouble with delayed expansion

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, command

All I am trying is to store a string in an array and then access them using variable as index.
I have tried Delayed Expansion, but I don't know what is wrong with code.
Please help.
The test.cmd file contains

```
@echo OFF
@set i=1
echo ENTER Your First Name :
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p input_value[%i%]=%=%
call:print
endlocal
@set i=2
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo ENTER Your Last Name :
set /p input_value[%i%]=%=%
call:print
endlocal
:print
@echo !input_value[%i%]!
GOTO:EOF
```

Output:

```
D:\backup_app\bat>test.cmd
ENTER Your First Name :
radhe
radhe
ENTER Your Last Name :
kishan
kishan
!input_value[2]!
```

The last line in the output is what that is troubling me.

Comment: What do you expect on `!input_value[2]!`? Try remove `endlocal` above `:print` and you will get *kishan*

Comment: I don't want !input_value[2]! in the output. But I am getting it.

Comment: Then you should refer JosefZ's answer

Comment: Insert `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` before `:print` label because you are "falling" into the `:print` routine a third time unintentionally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip over the `:print` procedure (an you could enable delayed expansion only to necessary code snippet) as follows:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableExtensions
@set i=1
echo ENTER Your First Name :
set /p input_value[%i%]=%=%
call:print
@set i=2

echo ENTER Your Last Name :
set /p input_value[%i%]=%=%
call:print
goto :next
:print
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !input_value[%i%]!
    endlocal
    GOTO:EOF
:next
```